# Maven compiles deleted files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, antlr

I'm using IntelliJ and Maven. ANTLR has generated some files, I have deleted them and then generated new ones, now every time I clean and compile, Maven will generate the old files but not the new files... Any ideas, please? How is that possible? Those old files are not anywhere in the project anymore.

Comment: Start by running `mvn clean install` from command line. Does this produce the correct output? If yes, the problem is with Idea, if not, the problem is within Maven/ANTLR build.

Answer (score 0):

Activate more logs with a `mvn -X clean install`: you will see that way which files the ANTLR uses for its AST transformations.

The idea is to check that it is applied on the right source files.

Comment: [DEBUG] Stale source detected: C:\Users\elusiven\IdeaProjects\exorsus\target\generated-sources\antlr4\exBaseListener.java that's the only thing that has something to do with the old files in the debug, also when I try to create a new file, and then clean install, i cannot reference it in the project anywhere and it's not even compiled. This is after cleaning btw... The target folder dissapears but after compile or install it keeps coming back with old files that do not even exist in the project.